# Python trying to set and get for radiobutton value. Error set() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, get, set

I am trying to use the .set and .get arguments to get the value of a chosen radio button and to then return a text string based on the value chosen.

I am returned the following error: `set() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

This is my code (btw there are all sorts of other bits in between but I've just pulled out the pieces relevant to my problem)

```
#Trying to set the values for the various radio buttons

self.lbl18 = Label(self.sub, text='Reports')
self.repType = StringVar()
self.repType.set()
self.rbPandN = Radiobutton(self.sub, text='Protected & Notable', 
variable=self.repType, value='pn')
self.rbAllSpec = Radiobutton(self.sub, text='All Species', 
variable=self.repType, value='as')
self.rbBats = Radiobutton(self.sub, text='Bats', variable=self.repType, 
value='bat')
self.rbGCN = Radiobutton(self.sub, text='GCN', variable=self.repType, 
value='gcn')

#Trying to get the value of the radio button to return the desired text  

if self.repType.get() == 'pn':
    emFile.write("\nA list of protected and notable species found within 
the search area.\n")
elif self.repType.get() == 'as':
    emFile.write("\nLists of protected and notable species and other 
species found within the search area.\n")
elif self.repType.get() == 'bat':
    emFile.write("\nBATS.\n")
else self.repType.get() == 'gcn':
    emFile.write("\nGCN.\n")
```

Comment: Can you please post the **full** error traceback? Also what package are `RadioButton`, `StringVar` and `Label` coming from? Why would you expect us to just know? -- My guess is that you need to pass a value to `self.repType.set()` (which makes sense).

Comment: Presumably this is TKInter

Comment: Yes, it is TKInter. I have tried passing the value 'pn' to .set() but now I get a different error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\ERIC North East\IT\ArcMap Python stuff\", line 1582, in <module>
    app = Application(master=root)
  File "G:\ERIC North East\IT\ArcMap Python stuff\ 8.pyw", line 784, in __init__
    self.createWidgets()
  File "G:\ERIC North East\IT\ArcMap Python stuff\Standalone mapping script\run_map_script v8.pyw", line 383, in createWidgets
    self.btnPickFile.gid(row=62, column=4, sticky=E, padx=5)
AttributeError: Button instance has no attribute 'gid'

Comment: @koofrith, That would mean that you solved this problem, and now you have another different one. That's programming for you. :)

Comment: Me https://knowyourmeme.com/photos/234765-i-have-no-idea-what-im-doing

Comment: @koofrith, obviously you wanted to write grid and not gid. Take care to read the error you get and try to think about what it tells you, then look at your code, especially where the error tells you to look and try to think what the error says is wrong

Comment: Mwah thank you @Eran It works now! Sorry, I'm a total novice to Programming and have been thrown in at the deep end due to a colleague's departure, so I'm learning. Probably need to do some basic training when there is time!

Answer (score 0):

`self.repType.set()` take a value and sets the StringVar to have this value. So you must give it a parameter of the value you want it to have (or not call it at all if you don't want to set a value). Calling it where you have can be used to have a default button selected, so if you have default use its value in the set, otherwise remove the call completely.

Example of call:

```
self.repType.set('pn')
```

Take a look at the example in http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm